# How to run update-apt-xapian-index only one time at week?

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, cron

I cannot understand why `update-apt-xapian-index` is starting every day I boot Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I have disabled updates in Muon but without any change. After that I searched for it in `/etc/cron.*` but found only one occurrence in `cron.weekly`:

```
$  grep -r "update-apt-xapian-index" /etc/cron.*
/etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index:CMD=/usr/sbin/update-apt-xapian-index
```

So this should not run it every day. The only information I have is `ps` output:

```
root      1951  0.7  0.2 167940 17060 ?        Sl   11:28   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apt-xapian-index/update-apt-xapian-index-dbus
root      1954 94.7  2.0 236216 166168 ?       R    11:28   0:10 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/update-apt-xapian-index --batch-mode --force --update
```

How can I make `update-apt-xapian-index` run only once a week?

Comment: It possibly is being started every day through systemd.

Comment: @vanadium Could you explain that more precisely?

Comment: Not out of the box. I only know that current linux systems use systemd for the startup procedure. That system, however, can also schedule processes and in this way replace cron. So it is not excluded that your process is being scheduled for a daily run by systemd.

Comment: vanadium is probably correct: https://github.com/chef/bento/issues/609#issuecomment-226043057, https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/18/ubuntu-16-04-auto-apt-update-and-apt-upgrade/#sec-7. @n0rbert has [a related bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1685376).

Comment: Still not knowing how is `xapian` starting, I found [this patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-xapian-index/+bug/1729882). Maybe this will help somebody.

Comment: "I have disabled updates in Muon" This is only about package updates and not related to your problem ! **You should re-enable it.**

Comment: You have not checked all cron files. Can you verify `sudo grep -ir xapian /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron` (note `/etc/cron*` not `/etc/cron.*`) ? If you find nothing and _xapian_ is currently running, you can search in `sudo journalctl -b` .

Comment: @user285259 I activated package update in Muon again.

The command `sudo grep -ir xapian /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron` returned nothing special `/etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index:CMD=/usr/sbin/update-apt-xapian-index`. I checked `sudo journalctl -b` but found no occurrences for _xapian_ and `xapian` was not running. After I run moun it started `update-apt-xapian-index-dbus` and run `update-apt-xapian-index` again. Maybe it will be handled by muon?